# Integrate $\int x\sqrt{1+\sec^4x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

I've been solving some homework in Area of a Surface of Revolution and this integration popped up, I couldn't solve it and can't find anything online about it, plus integral calculator can't solve it either?
$$
\int x \, \sqrt{1+\sec^4x} \, dx
$$

Here is the problem in the book, and no its the integral is supposed to be from 0 to $\pi/3$

Q1: Set up an integral for the area of the surface obtained by
rotating the curve about the $y$-axis:

a. $y= \tan(x)$

I posted it without limits because in my exam calculators are prohibited thus I cant use one and I have to find the integral first then substitute.

Comment: Can you please show the original problem of your homework in your post?

Comment: this does not look simple -- could you please post where this came from, as @user1046533 asked?

Comment: Also, your posting raises some side issues.  The most plausible explanation is that either you need a definite integral (instead), or you have made a prior analytical mistake.  Assuming that this is not the case, then if the problem is from a book or class, it is not a good idea to either attack the problem in  a vacuum or present the problem in a vacuum.   For one thing, assuming that a book/class is involved, does it involve Complex Analysis or only Real Analysis?  ...see next comment

Comment: Although it can be cumbersome to do so, my first step here would be to carefully analyze all of the worked examples, previous exercises and theorems that I think might be relevant.  Further, in accordance with [this article on MathSe protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236), I would include all of these pertinent details directly in your posting, for the benefit of the MathSE reviewers.

Comment: I have updated the question with the question in my home work and the limits

Comment: Are you sure this wasn't a "set up but do not evaluate" kind of problem?

Comment: Good reply.  Just to clarify: are you saying that the actual integral is $$\int_0^{\pi/3} x\sqrt{1+\sec^4x}\ dx ~?$$ Also, is the exercise requiring you to *set up the integral*, which you have already done, or *evaluate the integral*?

Comment: @user2661923 yes exactly!

Comment: Are you supposed to set up the integral or evaluate the integral?

Comment: evaluate, the thing is i was worried that some kind of question like that would pop up in my exam! since we aren't allowed to use calculator, but im guessing this type of questions cant be solved without a calculator, right?

Comment: I am guessing that this kind of problem can't be solved unless the problem solver is extremely talented at finding elegant ways to evaluate definite integrals.  You keep ducking what to me is a critical question.  What is your best guess as to the tools that the problem composer intends that you use?  I would expect these tools to be represented by previous exercises, worked examples, and theorems.  I suspect that well over (1/2) of the pertinent problem composers are **not** deranged.  This implies that the problem composer believes that you have been given tools to attack the problem.

Comment: I imagine you can't get a closed form for $\int_0^{\pi/3}x\sqrt{1+\sec^4x}dx$ with the tools expected of you at this stage, but the question only wanted you to "set up" the integral. You've done that.

Comment: @J.G. I suspect that you are right.  However, I asked that question point blank, and the first word in the OP's last comment was "*evaluate*".

Comment: Maybe that's in an unstated Q2.

Comment: @J.G. Then, what is the problem composer's intent?  What tools did the problem composer intend that the problem solver use?

Comment: Mathematica is not able to solve it.

Comment: @user2661923 Based on Q1, not evaluation. I won't guess the intent behind a hypothetical Q2 we haven't even read.

Comment: It looks like you've considered $\int xds$ rather than $\int y ds$, [which is much nicer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28tan+x%29*sqrt%281%2B%28sec+x%29%5E4%29). Maybe the question author meant to ask for rotation about the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

You made an error in setting up your integral. Instead of putting $\tan x$ in front of the radical, you put just $x$.  The integral for calculating the surface area should really be $SA=2\pi\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}\tan x\sqrt{1+\sec^4x}\ dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no much hope for a solution, use a series solution
$$\sqrt{1+\sec ^4(x)}=\sqrt 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac {a_n}{(2n)!} x^{2n}$$ the first $a_n$ making the unknown sequence
$$\{1,1,11,211,5921,237121,14592731,1371063331,164080073441,\cdots\}$$

Using only the terms given above, this leads to a value of $1.26193$ while numerical integration gives $1.26294$. Using twice more terms, it would be $1.2629384$ instead of $1.2629409$